# Why is my rdlc report displaying a blankreport?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm trying to diplay a rdlc report in my MVC project. I created 2 addtional folders :
 - one for my dataset
 - one containing my `rdlc` report file and my webform `aspx` file. Below is my code for the `Page_Load` event of the webform

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Models.goodcustomers> goodcustomers= null;
                using (var dc = new MaDbContext())
                {
                    goodcustomers= dc.goodcustomers.ToList();
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/RPTReports/goodcustomers.rdlc");
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    ReportDataSource rdc = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", goodcustomers);
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdc);
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Webform code**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true">

        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is not working.... What happens is that when the page opens, it prints the cells FOR ALL the items in `List<Models.goodcustomers>` BUT those cells are blank.
Obviously when I was debugging I saw that everything was retrieved from the database. So I guess this is not a database connectio issue

`goodcustomers` is a view in my database fro which I have created a Model in my MVC application and I'm using DbContext code first to query the database

Any idea of what is going on ?

ps : to display the Webform in my MVC application I just use an `<a>` tag with href pointing to the location of the `aspx` file

Comment: Sounds like there is not database issue, this may be rendering issue. Check if those data are really exist in page source by viewing HTML in browser inspector, post output HTML contents if necessary.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Check my solution in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on a website. Three things  should be done here :

- 1 : convert `goodcustomers` to a `DataTable`. Then pass that `DataTable` as parameter in `ReportDataSource rdc = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", goodcustomers_converted_to_DataTable);`
- 2 : **BIND** the data. Add `ReportViewer1.DataBind();` right below `rdc` instantiation
- 3 : Step 2 should correct the issue. Now is you want to displace the webform in an MVC cshtml view, use `<iFrame>` with src pointing to the aspx webform.

Following those 3 steps solved my problem.